# Internal Name not working in Content Query Web Part on SPS2007

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt

I'm trying to get and display list columns in the Content Query Web Part.  Unfortunatley, some of these column names are like "WEC_ArchiveDate" or "My Categories".  So I find the internal SharePoint name and add them in the commonFields section in the CQWP however the data contained in these columns do not appear. (Columns without spaces appear just fine).

What could I be doing wrong?

Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

please replace spaces with x0020: http://www.rnowik.com/Converting-sharepoint-display-name-to-internal-name.aspx
you can also use SharePoint Manager to see actual internal name of the field: http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: Ivan, thanks for the reply but I have already tried that. I am trying to get the column "Issue Date and using the Internal Name of "ISSUE_x0020_DATE". but its not displaying the data. I created a special XSLT template to just dump the XML so I can see what I am getting.

Comment: @Bismarck: Case matters when you are using internal column names. What about `Issue_x0020_Date`?